# MVC 4 DotNetOpenAuth - LinkedIn: not grabbing Email Address

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, linkedin-api, dotnetopenauth

I am using the built-in MVC 4 OAuthWebSecurity to allow authentication for LinkedIn.

On my LinkedIn API key, I added r_emailaddress permissions.

[image]

The problem is the email address is not getting populated in the ExtraData dictionary for some reason in the result object.

```
AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
```

[image]

Any ideas on how i can leverage the built-in LinkedIn provider, but retrieve the email address?

**UPDATE**
It turns out the built-in DotNetAuthOpenAuth provider for LinkedIn does not populate the email-address field.... 
Also, the user name field gets populated with the user's full name as well.
So, it is a bit odd to say the least.

Anyway, I found this link http://deepindera.blogspot.com/2013/08/aspnet-mvc-oauth-linkedin-email-problem.html, which shows you how to create a custom LinkedIn client for DotNetAuth.

Answer (score 0):

Email address was removed from profile and can be obtained in separate request only
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/primary-contact-api#retrieve-email-address

Also you should now, that some users doesn't have any email address assigned.

> The API call would return empty response body if the authenticated user was registered via phone number, and never added any primary email address into their LinkedIn account previously. The value of type is case sensitive, and can only be EMAIL in this case.